# Implementing callback functions in C

Tags: c

I am a newbie to C. I am trying to implement callback function using function pointers.

I am getting an error

```
:test_callback.c:10: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘void’
```

when I try to compile the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void (*callback) (void);

void callback_proc ()
{
  printf ("Inside callback function\n");
}

void register ((void (*callback) (void)))
{
  printf ("Inside registration \n");
  callback (); /* Calling an initial callback with function pointer */
}

int main ()
{
  callback = callback_proc;/* Assigning function to the function pointer */
  register (callback);/* Passing the function pointer */
  return 0;
}
```

---

What is this error?Can anyone help?

Comment: `register` is a keyword, BTW.

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: Just a tip: typedefs help make things a little more readable: `typedef void (*CallbackFunc)(void);`. Then your function signature is `void registerFunc(CallbackFunc callback)` and your declarations are `CallbackFunc my_cb = &callback_proc`

Comment: Oh, one more thing: `void callback_proc ()` is NOT THE SAME as `void callback_proc (void)` in C.

Answer (score 19):

1. `register` is a C keyword: Use another name for the function.
2. You have extra parantheses around the callback parameter. It should be:

   ```
   void funcName(void (*callback) (void))
   ```

Comment: Yep, the extra parens was hard to catch. +1

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use a typedef

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef void (*callback_t) (void);
callback_t callback;

void callback_proc(void)
{
    printf ("Inside callback function\n");
}

void reg( callback_t _callback )
{
    printf ("Inside registration \n");
    _callback();
}

int main ()
{
    callback = callback_proc;
    reg(callback);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: removed the register issue

Comment: where is the typedef ? that's a very good recommendation, but your example is missing it.

Comment: I fail to see the typedef? What you've done is defined a function pointer, which is not type safe.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize that I had a problem with copy and paste

Answer (score 2):

You can't use 'register' as a function name as it's a C keyword.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

- you can't use the name `register` as it's a keyword (not used often anymore, but it's still there)
- change the definition of the function from

  ```
  void wasRegister((void (*callback) (void)))
  ```

  to:

  ```
  void wasRegister(void (*callback) (void))
  ```

  (get rid of the parens around the parameter's declaration.

Also you might get a warning about `callback_proc()` not having a matching delaration to the `callback` variable (depending on how you compile the program - as C or C++), so you might want to change its declaration to:

```
void callback_proc (void)
```

to make it explicit that it takes no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [type safe callbacks](http://ccan.ozlabs.org/info/typesafe_cb.html) from [ccan](http://ccan.ozlabs.org). Its one thing to expose a typed function pointer for the world to use, its another to ensure sane casting.

Comment: Hi Tim, the link in your answer is dead.

Comment: @bummi, if Tim ever decides to delete this answer, He'll get a message *This post was deleted by Tim Post♦. To know why your answer was deleted please use meta* :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef void (*callback_func) (void);

static callback_func the_callback = 0;

void process (void)
{
  printf ("Inside process function\n");
}

void callback_register (callback_func cb)
{
  the_callback = cb;
  printf ("Inside registration \n");
}

void callback(void)
{
    the_callback();
}

int main (void)
{
  callback_register(process); /* Passing the function pointer */
  callback();
  return 0;
}
```

Declaring `the_callback` static would make more sense if this code was modularized and then you would be forced to call `callback_register` in order to set it, and `callback` in order to call it - `the_callback` would not be accessible outside of the implementation (.c) only the function declarations would be in the header (.h).